# Creating an Angular code sharing project won't generate a webpack file

Tags: angular, webpack, nativescript, sharing

I am all new to nativescript, and because I would really like to be able to preview my app in my browser before doing it on my phone (it's a lot more convenient this way, isn't it?), I need to create a code sharing project.

So I run this command given in the doc:

```
ng new --collection=@nativescript/schematics project-name --shared
```

Which seems to execute all fine with no issue. But I noticed the project generated from this command has no webpack.config.js file which you get when generating a normal project.
[Screenshot of the project root folder right after command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wiq7.jpg)

Missing this file causes commands like *tns preview --bundle* or *tns run android --bundle* to not work.

I did find the package **nativescript-dev-webpack** that after installing manually generates a default webpack file, but I run into issue using this one (first of all because it uses modules in a deprecated way which even after fixing it causes the app to crash when running on Android).

My question is: is a code sharing project not supposed to generate a webpack file by default?
I've tried this on two different computers and got the same issue.

Thanks!

Comment: I have tested your command (tsn 6.7.8). It works as expected, including webpack.config.ts.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have installed Nativescript 7 and  nativescript/schematics 10
then run in your project folder :
tns migrate
then  modify the tsconfig.json with the following changes:

1. add on compilerOptions :  "importHelpers": true

2)rearrange paths @src/*  as following:

```
"src/*.ts",
"src/*.android.ts",
"src/*.ios.ts",
"src/*.tns.ts",
"src/*.web.ts"
```